# How to pursuade someone not believing in fortune telling

Tags: mahayana, zen

How to persuade someone not to be too superstitious or too much into fortune telling? Cause based on the answers below, it's not appropriate.

[Did the Lord Buddha say anything about magic and fortune telling?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=fortune%20telling)

[Do Buddhist believe fortune teller?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/7440/do-buddhist-believe-fortune-teller)

I shared the link above, the common answers below are mostly from senior Buddhists.

1. Buddhism has evolved, those sutta could outdated.
2. Those are Theravada, and Mahayana version is different. We have too many branches.
3. Many success stories of healing including themself.

Most cases from the "un-audited" or modified Buddhism below from a single person thought.

1. [Modified Chan Buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/46082/the-story-of-ji-gong-%E6%BF%9F%E5%85%AC)
2. [Modified Mahayana](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/46116/xin-ling-fa-men-%E5%BF%83%E7%81%B5%E6%B3%95%E9%97%A8-new-buddhism/46125#46125)

Answer (score 0):

> How to persuade someone not to be too superstitious or too much into fortune telling? Cause based on the answers below, it's not appropriate.

We can't really (nor is it our job) to persuade anyone to do anything.

People have their own Kamma and go in their own direction in Samsara.
The most we can do is to be good (Buddhist) examples ourselves and thereby maybe inspire others but its not something we actively strive for. If it happens then its positive and if not, then that's fine as well.

Comment: just happened to some good friends and has a compassionate heart. So would like to help only. Some just complaint Buddhism is not helping. This could be the reason